# New Property in udm.DeploymentPackage as disabled in xldeploy

Tags: xl-deploy

XLDeploy allows its CI to be extended by adding entry in synthetic.xml.

i modified synthetic.xml and added a new property:

```
<type-modification type="udm.DeploymentPackage">
<property name="notes" kind="string"/>
```

i can see this property on UI now:

[image]

However i want this field to be Disabled or Readonly. Can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read-only field in a CI feature is not implemented yet .. what you can do if you're not going to change it during deployment is to define a hidden field with a default value.

```
<type-modification type="udm.DeploymentPackage">
<property name="notes" kind="string" default="My Custom Notes" hidden="true"/>
```

If you want this to be visible then you will need to define 2 properties one visible and another hidden.

The visible would be a display text field. 
The hidden would be what is actually used.

You can then make sure the description is clear that even if a user changes this value, it will remain at the default.

```
<type-modification type="udm.DeploymentPackage">
<property name="hiddenNotes" kind="string" default="My Custom Notes" hidden="true"/>
<property name="notes" kind="string" default="My Custom Notes" hidden="false" description="Changing this will not affect actual value, it will remain at the default"/>
```